# Why the object has no attribute 'tbody'?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, beautifulsoup

I'm just a beginner python learner mainly data scraping due to my job and I'm trying to get the reason for having no attribute 'tbody'.There is clearly in tbody tag in HTML, how it cant find. It's just a simple Wikipedia data scraping script, here are the codes can someone help me?

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

URL='https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_real_GDP_growth_rate'
response=requests.get(URL)
soup= BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
columns=['World Rank','Country','Real GDP Growth Rate %']

table=soup.find('table',{'class':'wikitable sortable jquery-tablesorter'}).tbody

df=pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)
trs=table.find_all('tr')

for tr in trs:
    tds = tr.find_all('td')
    row = [td.text.replace('\n','') for td in tds]
    df =df.append(pd.Series(row, index=columns),ignore_index=True)

df.to_csv('real gdp growth rate.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: yes, but when I run my script it doesn't find it.

Comment: why not use pandas read_html to grab all tables?

Comment: @QHarr thank you, can you please guide me a bit ?

Comment: import pandas as pd: tables = pd.read_html('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_real_GDP_growth_rate')   then use index to retrieve required table.

Answer (score 1):

If you check with F12 (aka. dev tools) it will "always" show a tbody on any table, even if there's not in the original code. This should be enough :

```py
soup.find('table',{'class':'wikitable sortable jquery-tablesorter'}).findAll('tr')
```

Comment: again I got this AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'findAll', I guess the main issue is in the table class ?

Comment: Can you check if `soup.find('table',{'class':'wikitable sortable jquery-tablesorter'})` gives you `None` ? It would mean the selectors are not correct. If it's `None`, try this : `findAll('table')[0]` just to see if it can get a table on the page.

Comment: Yes that worked thank you so much, even though I'm still having some errors it was useful. Error is Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "realgdpgrowthrate.py", line 17, in <module>
    df =df.append(pd.Series(row, index=columns),ignore_index=True)
  File "C:\Users\eren\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 249, in __init__
    .format(val=len(data), ind=len(index)))
ValueError: Length of passed values is 0, index implies 3